# Non Ascii character export on csv with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I have a list of lists and I export it on a csv. Some of the lists entities are strings and some them with non-ascii characters.

For example: Name = "Ömer Berin"

I try Name.encode('utf-8'), before exporting but on the csv the name show like this "Γ–mer Berin"

I use this code for exporting:

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

UnicodeWriter should satisfy your needs http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples